# Android gradle access is denied

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
C:\Users\mahmo\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4\docs\dsl\org.gradle.api.reporting.dependents.DependentComponentsReport.html (Access is denied)
```

This error message appear whenever I open any project in the android studio

Comment: which gradle version you can use and also which Android Studio version u can use ?

Answer (score 0):

[FIXED] try to remove the Read Only and Hidden properties of the .gradle folder (and all sub folders)